# vlookup not finding vba cells

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a table that uses a bit of vba to populate column b with id numbers.

I then have column c as a `vlookup` that gets a name based off the id, from another sheet. The `vlookup` in the first cell works fine and returns the correct name, John Doe.

When I drag down, the rest of the cells in column c return the same name as the first, John Doe. The `vlookup` in the other cells is exactly the same, except the reference cell does change, as expected....so, `c2 = vlookup(b2, $range, col, false)`, `c3= vlookup(b3..)`, `c4=vlookup(b4,..)`, etc.

The catch is, when I look at the `vlookup` in c3 and click on b3, the cell changes to find the correct name (no longer John Doe). So it works fine. And I have to do that for every cell in column c.

It's like `vlookup` isn't aware that column b changed? Is that something that happens with vba? Is there a refresh command or some other way for `vlookup` to register that column b has changed without having to click on each individual `vlookup` function?

Comment: @EngJon I don't think he has any code if I'm reading it right.  db2381 is it possible you're workbook/worksheet has automatic calculation turned off?  I was able to recreate your issue when I turned the calculation option to manual.

Comment: Please include your code and format your question so that it is not just one big blob of text.

Comment: Automatic calculation mode is turned on? Formulas tab -> Calculation Options -> Automatic

Answer (score 0):

If you've entered a formula in a cell, then copied the formula to another cell and Excel hasn't updated your results, that means that `Calculation Mode` is `Manual`.

To fix it (depending on version, this is for Excel 2010)

1. Click on `Formulas` in the Ribbon
2. Click on `Calculation Options`
3. Click on `Automatic`

If you need to have it calculate manually (valuable for making many formula changes in a large worksheet):

1. Click on `Formulas` in the Ribbon
2. Click on `Calculate Now` to calculate the entire workbook, or
3. Click on `Calculate Sheet` to calculate the current worksheet

You can skip all the clicking by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> to `Calculate Now` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> to `Calculate Sheet`.